# On my FireFox status bar a contextual ad? (Possible Adware?)

Tags: firefox, malware

What is it? How did I get it? I am assuming is spyware/malware and I should get rid of it.

[image]

Comment: What add-ons do you have installed?

Comment: see my comment @Daniel below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's Google Reader Notifier. The latest version has spam.

[Source: Beware! Google Reader Notifier for Firefox Is Now Crapware](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/2585/beware-google-reader-notifier-for-firefox-is-now-crapware/) (also contains instructions on how to remove it)

Comment: No way.. crazy!

Answer (score 0):

Did you look in Addon's from the Tools menu?

Comment: Yes, it seems to look clean. Extensions: Delicious; Google Reader Notifier; MS .Net 1.1.  Plugins:Office, Acrobat,Default, Quicktime, Shockwave, Silverlight, WPF.

Comment: I'll try disabling each extension and see if one of them is responsible for it.

Comment: I disabled Google Reader Notifier, then restarted, now its gone... I renabled Google Reader Notifier, restarted, its still gone. I wonder if it will come back.

Answer (score 0):

My first guess is that this is an addon.  Go to Tools > Add-Ons and look for any add-ons that you don't want installed.  Try disabling any suspicious add-ons, then restarting to see if it fixes the problem.  If it does, then you can go back to the add-ons window and uninstall that one.  Otherwise, you can reenable the add-on.

If you can be sure that it's not an add-on, you may have a bad copy of Firefox.  Firefox is open source, so it's entirely possible that you downloaded a modified version from somewhere on the web.  You may wish to delete your copy of Firefox and download a sure-to-be-valid copy from http://www.getfirefox.com.  If you wish, you can make a backup of your firefox profile, to easily make your new copy seem like your old one (hopefully without the ad!).  You can learn about this at [support.mozilla.com/kb/Profiles](http://support.mozilla.com/kb/Profiles).

Answer (score 0):

check if you have FireSaver installed as an addon, it has spam